# Woocommerce: How can I use Stripe ONLY for single payments? I want to turn it off for subscriptions payments

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I am trying to disable Stripe for subscription payments and show it for ONLY single payments, as in one time payments only.

I came across the below code, but this does the opposite. I need it doing so it hides for subscriptions and shows for single payments (one time payments)

```html
function so23120782_maybe_remove_stripe( $available_gateways ) {

    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Cart' ) && ( ! WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription() || ( isset( $_GET['order_id'] ) && ! WC_Subscriptions_Order::order_contains_subscription( $_GET['order_id'] ) ) ) ) {
        if ( isset( $available_gateways['stripe'] ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['stripe'] );
        }
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'so23120782_maybe_remove_stripe', 11 );
```

Comment: The following removes PayPal as an option for subscription products - may of some use / easy to change to stripe. https://github.com/Prospress/woocommerce-subscriptions-disable-paypal/blob/master/woocommerce-disable-paypal-for-subscriptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just change the condition when to unset stripe:

```
if ( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Cart' ) && ( WC_Subscriptions_Cart::cart_contains_subscription() || ( isset( $_GET['order_id'] ) &&  WC_Subscriptions_Order::order_contains_subscription( $_GET['order_id'] ) ) ) ) {
```

(I have removed the "not" -- ! -- from the conditions, which should be fine)